# ListBox won't show data horizontally in multiple columns WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I read here some posts on that issue and still didn't found a solution to my problem, also I have used this [guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19395.multiple-columns-in-wpf-listbox.aspx).

My ListBox still showing as a long list with a ScrollViewer, and not Horizontally as I refer to.

XAML: **EDITED!**

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" IsEnabled="{Binding IsWindowEnabled}" MinWidth="724" Background="Red">
    <!-- save notifictaion popup -->
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" FontSize="15" Foreground="Green" Content="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._123}" x:Name="ML_0003" />
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0">
        <Label Content="Select Constant Type" Margin="0 0 10 0" />
        <ComboBox Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboNames}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedComboType}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Combos}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelecetedCombo}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 5">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Index}" Margin="10 0" Width="20" />
                    <TextBox Width="150" Margin="0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

But Still my List Looks like that:

IMAGE: **EDITED No.2**

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: First try putting `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the ListBox. Then it should stretch horizontally to fit its parent. Getting alignment the way you want in a `DockPanel` can be tricky as well.

Comment: I've tried it, with no success.

Comment: Is the DockPanel inside a Grid? Or what? In WPF, everything is laid out relative to its parent. Is this whole thing inside a TabItem? Or what?

Comment: No, the DockPanel is inside the UserControl without something around it.

Comment: @Tuco got it. The only thing wrong is the Width attribute on the ListBox. You set a fixed width of 220, so of course that's how big it is. Just remove that attribute, ignore his advice to set a different wrong value.

Comment: Removed the Width attribute from the ListBox, uses "HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", the ListBox is now stretch in the window but my list is still appears as one long column.

Comment: Can you post the current XAML?

Comment: I have edit my XAML to current state, also updated the Picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129361/discussion-between-orionlk-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: Do you have code behind affecting the UI?

Comment: @Tuco No there isn't.

Comment: Did you revert it back to wrap panel just like the example on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change the ItemPanel from

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

To

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Ignore the above suggestion.

**EDIT**

Could you please try to give a background color to internal stack panel you have used in DataTemplate? like

```
<DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="Blue" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 5">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Index}" Margin="10 0" Width="20" />
                    <TextBox Width="150" Margin="0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

It will give you an idea that how stackpanel is taking the space in ListBox items. Then we can try to adjust the width of each ListBoxItem

**EDIT 2**

This is what I see on my side

[image: Output]

and XAML is

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_StackOverFlow_Lab.Test1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_StackOverFlow_Lab"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" IsEnabled="{Binding IsWindowEnabled}" MinWidth="724" Background="Red">
    <!-- save notifictaion popup -->
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" FontSize="15" Foreground="Green" Content="Constants Configuration" x:Name="ML_0003" />
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0">
        <Label Content="Select Constant Type" Margin="0 0 10 0" />
        <ComboBox Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboNames}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedComboType}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Combos}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelecetedCombo}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 5">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Index}" Margin="10 0" Width="20" />
                    <TextBox Width="150" Margin="0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Changed it to StackPanel and still with no success, the Width was also changed to Bigger value, also tried "Auto" and also removed this property, still one column :(

Comment: @Orionlk This is mistaken. `WrapPanel` behaves identically to `StackPanel` in every respect that's relevant to the question.

Comment: Tried the Background="LightBlue" thing, Edited my Pic in my post, still don't work.

Comment: @Orionlk, I think the inner stack panel is expanding it to all the space. Do one thing. set the width of this stack panel to `Width=190`, and lets see what happens

Comment: @MuhammadUmmar, It just colored the StackPanel around the items, as expeced, and as well depends on the ListBox parent Width if more or less. The ListBox all works as expected, it hust refused to show in multiple column.

Comment: @Orionlk, Please have a look on **Edit 2**, this is what I see on my side with your XAML.

Comment: @MuhammadUmmar, Thanks, it works in a different window, but in my specific window it's still NOT. I'll leave it like this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set a width of 220 in your listbox, and since the items are in wrap panel, they will show vertically, try to increase the width

```
<ListBox Width="220" [OTHER PROPERTIES]>
```

Increase the width

```
<ListBox Width="520" [OTHER PROPERTIES]>
```

Or if your design allows it, delete the width property and let the listbox fill it's parent

Comment: He shouldn't be using a fixed width at all. He should just remove the Width attribute so it fills the parent.

Comment: Good idea, do that, but still the list is just on one big column.

Comment: @Orionlk Just for testing, try setting the DockPanel's Background to Red to see if its filling its parent. If it's not filling its own parent, set the DockPanel's HorizontalAlignment to Stretch

Comment: Good thinking! but after changed DockPanel's Background to Red it does fill its parent. tried to set the DockPanel's HorizontalAlignment to Stretch, and still nothing. Just FYI - this UserControl have a parent that calls it

Comment: @EdPlunkett Edited my XAML and Picture to current state.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ListBox uses a panel called VirtualizingStackPanel to arrange its items
vertically.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```